# Перебор массива с шагом 2

Tags: javascript

Есть массив из элементов которого нужно создать двумерный массив с шагом 2.

input

```
let elems = [ '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

output

```
let newarr = [
  [1,3],
  [2,4]
]
```

Сам додумался до чего-то такого, но получается массив с 4 элементами, а не с двумя

```
let newarr = []

let elems = [ '1', '2', '3', '4']

for (var i=0; i <= 3; i=i+1) {
  newarr.push(Array.from(elems[i]))
}

for (var i=1; i <= 3; i=i+2) {
  newarr.push(Array.from(elems[i]))
}
```

Comment: Если править ваше решение, то `newarr = [[], []]`. В первом цикле `i+1` заменить на `i+2`. Первый цикл добавляет элементы в первый вложенный массив `newarr[0].push(elems[i])`, второй цикл добавляет элементы во второй вложенный массив `newarr[1].push(elems[i])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сформировать массив так:

Вы проходитесь по оригинальному массиву с помощью [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), нечетные индексы идут в первый массив, четные - во второй (условие с [оператором остатка](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#vzyatie-ostatka) я задал [тернарным оператором](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) для удобочитаемости). После этого добавляем оба новых массива в конечный массив.

```
let newarr = [],
elems = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
f = [],
s = [];

elems.forEach((n, i) => ((i % 2) ? s : f).push(n)); 

newarr.push(f, s);
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: `elems.indexOf(n) % 2 === 0` - ужас.

Comment: Ужас - это про само использование indexOf, а не про сравнение с нулём.

Comment: @highpassion, коллбэк `forEach` получает индекс элемента массива во втором параметре, поэтому эффективнее просто брать этот индекс вместо его поиска (`indexOf` это лишний проход по массиву на каждой итерации): `elems.forEach((n, idx) => ((idx % 2) ? scd : first).push(n));` - у Quertiy в ответе тот же принцип.

Comment: @yar85 большое спасибо, еще не использовал так, стоит повнимательнее доки читать )

Comment: @yar85, это не только лишний проход по массиву, превращающий O(n) в O(n**2), но и неправильный индекс если в массиве есть повторяющиеся элементы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, очень верное замечание. О нюансе с дублирующимися значениями я не подумал.

Answer (score 2):

Вот 3 способа - выбирай:

```js
let elems = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let a = [], b = []

for (let i=0; i<elems.length; ++i) {
  (i & 1 ? b : a).push(elems[i])
}

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

```js
let elems = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let a = [], b = []
elems.forEach((x, i) => (i & 1 ? b : a).push(x))

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

```js
let elems = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let [a, b] = elems.reduce((res, x, i) => (res[i&1].push(x), res), [[], []])

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Comment: @yar85, блин, точно, последствия копипаста из цикла. Причём, я же даже хотел исправить когда поправил такое же в reduce, но успешно об этом забыл))